# jquery UI Tabs Ajax cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, jquery, cakephp-1.3, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to use the [jQuery UI Tabs Ajax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) to load some tabs content via Ajax. Everything works, content is loaded and everything, but the problem I'm having is this:

Let's say I have the following tab in a cakePHP view file:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'my_controller', 'action' => 'my_action')); ?>">Tabs 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the `href` attibute of my `a` element points to a controller action (`controller => my_controller and action => my_action`) in this case. The problem I'm having is that, when I first load the page, the action `my_action` is actually executed BEFORE I even click on the tab. How do I prevent this from happening? Obviously, I want `my_action` to be called only when I click on the tabs.

Any help please

Thank you

Comment: i don't think this is right. According to the manual on url it generates the url without actually calling the action. IMO something else is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste my_action from my_controller, and app_controller beforeRender function? I try an answer without a partial code from your app

I think is a render problem.. Or check you app_controller (beforeRender) ... 
First of all, in the controller, you need $this->layout = 'ajax';
Second, in the app_controller, don't load the layout because it stop the ajax. (or you can "protect" your layout from your app_controller trough a condition)